# Filtering a database based on the content of another

Tags: python, pandas

So I need to assign a new dataframe of features without protected attributes; I'm provided 2 .csv's where one has all information for each instance and another which labels each column as 1 if the attribute is a protected feature, 2 if the attribute is the value to be predicted, and 0 otherwise.

I'm not entirely certain how to go about this since I'm not very well versed but from my understanding it would be something similar to

```
df = pd.read_csv("x.csv")
pdf = pd.read_csv("y.csv")

newDf = df.iloc[? && pdf[cols?]]
```

So, given 2 different dataframes with the same labels:

```
  A B C
0 7 3 1
1 8 3 1 
2 9 2 1
```

```
  A B C 
0 0 1 1
```

Expected output would be:

```
  A
0 7
1 8 
2 9
```

Comment: Explain your question with considered input and expected output?

Comment: editied for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with negation to find all the columns with `0` value in second dataframe (`df2`) and use that as a list of columns to fetch from `df1`:

```
df[list(df.columns.to_series().loc[~df2.any()])]
```

Output:

```
    A
0   7
1   8
2   9
```

Comment: I've been rushing through this assignment and I've been overlooking runtime, BUT I do appreciate the adjustment and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Below is the output as per my understanding of your question, tell me if I am mistaken.

```
df1:
    A   B   C   D
0   7   3   1   6
1   8   3   1   4
2   9   1   1   1

df2:
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   1   0
```

```
df3=pd.DataFrame()
for i in df1.columns:
    if df2[i][0]==0:
        df3[i]=df1[i]

o/p:
df3:
    A   D
0   7   6
1   8   4
2   9   1
```

Comment: For loop for this is horrible. Avoid For loops as much as possible.

Comment: This works! Thank you for your answer and sorry about the previous confusion!

Comment: @calbhong This solution will take abundant amount of time for bigdata. *avoid for loops*